# Does the h5py file context manager automatically close files?

Tags: python, h5py, contextmanager

I've been using `f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')` for a while, and it requires closing with `f.close()` at the end.

Recently I discovered that I can do:

```
with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as f:
     # code to manipulate the file
```

However I'm not sure: Does this "context manager" (as they call it on [their page](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html#core-concepts)) automatically close the file or do I still have to add `f.close()` at the end?

I tried to find the answer in the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html), but the context manager is only mentioned in a one-liner during the Quickstart guide and apparently no further info about it is there.

Comment: `h5py.File.__exit__()` does nothing but doing a guarded call to [`close()`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/4b5a901fb297f6ae5a51ff992aa8a626a7f3c3a2/h5py/_hl/files.py#L360)

Comment: If it doesn't, that's a bug report waiting to be made.

Comment: Okay, that's a yes I guess. Thought so, but wasn't sure and didn't find further specifics in the h5py doc.

Comment: Meanwhile it is documented here: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html#appendix-creating-a-file and here: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/whatsnew/2.0.html#file-objects-must-be-manually-closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, the context manager automatically closes the file.